# How to make an angle bracket (&lt; and &gt;) close with tags in html

Tags: html, css

am working on project that involves writing a complete html element i.e putting the tags in between the angle bracket <html>, it's works but the tags and the angle brackets are having some padding or margin or space, but I want it close just like it will normally shows in text-editors. Check this W3Schools example http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp and this is my code and working example https://jsbin.com/nilaku/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get rid of the spaces before and after the less than and greater than signs that enclose HTML tags, you should place all elements that correspond to a single line in the output file on a single line in the source file. For example, for the `<html>` tag you should have all these 3 elements on one line:

```
<span class="ltbrac">&lt;</span><span class="eleme">html</span><span class="gtbrac">&gt;</span>
```

The following article shows some other possible solutions, too:

[Remove Whitespace Between Inline Elements](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Comment: I didn't notice that before, Thanks for the reply it works.